# How to stop or pause Quartz job

Tags: c#, quartz.net, aspnetboilerplate

I have executed 2 jobs (`MyJob1` and `MyJob2`) as below:

```cs
public async Task < ActionResult > ScheduleJob() {
  await _jobManager.ScheduleAsync < MyJob1 > (
    job => {
      job.WithIdentity("Job1Identity", "MyGroup")
        .WithDescription("This is job 1");
    },
    trigger => {
      trigger.StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(schedule => {
          schedule.RepeatForever()
            .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
            .Build();
        });
    });

  await _jobManager.ScheduleAsync < MyJob2 > (
    job => {
      job.WithIdentity("Job2Identity", "MyGroup")
        .WithDescription("This is job 2");
    },
    trigger => {
      trigger.StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(schedule => {
          schedule.RepeatForever()
            .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
            .Build();
        });
    });

  return Content("OK, scheduled!");
}
```

--> I have tried to use `_jobManager`.Stop() but it stops all my job, so how to stop or pause only  `MyJob2`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Scheduler.PauseJob`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#pauseJob(org.quartz.JobKey)) like this:

```
var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.PauseJob(new JobKey("Job2Identity", "MyGroup"));
```